# Simplifying two LINQ queries with joins and grouping

Tags: c#, linq

I have two static classes with fields decorated with `DisplayAttribute`s. One contains fields describing individual policies which indicate their parent role in the attribute. Another static class contains fields describing the roles.

How can I combine `q1` and `q2`, currently I am not clear how to perform the grouping which occurs in `q2` and retain the scope the `role`.

```
var roles = typeof(AuthRoles).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
    .OrderBy(a => a.Order)
    .Select(a => new { Id = a.ShortName, a.Name, a.Description, a.Order });

var policies = typeof(AuthPolicies).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
    .Select(a => new { Id = a.ShortName, a.Name, RoleId = a.GroupName, a.Description });

var q1 =
    from role in roles
    join policy in policies on role.Id equals policy.RoleId
    select new { role, policy };

var q2 =
    from item in q1
    group item by item.role.Id
    into grp
    select new
    {
        Role = grp.Select(g => new
        {
            Id = g.role.Id,
            Name = g.role.Name,
            Description = g.role.Description,
            Order = g.role.Order
        }).First(),
        Policies = grp.Select(g => new
        {
            Id = g.policy.Id,
            Name = g.policy.Name,
            Description = g.policy.Description
        }).OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToArray()
    };
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're combining them now?

Comment: I thought the use of two queries was merely a product of my lack of knowledge on how to perform it with a single query a simpler form. I gather there is no simpler way?

Comment: You would have to use a Join.  Most people say the way you are doing it is more efficient than use the join.  The join would put more data into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `join` the two sources in `q1` and then group them in `q2`, you can use the LINQ group join to gather the group directly:

```
var q1q2 =
    from Role in roles
    join policy in policies on Role.Id equals policy.RoleId into pj
    select new { Role, Policies = pj.Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Name, p.Description }).ToArray() };
```